# Regex improvement requested

Tags: regex

I have the following text

```
Dallas*  Garland - 7109-GAR * Closed* On Alert* Inclement Weather Closing*
Dallas*  Plano - 7207-PLA * Closed* On Alert* Power Outage*
Nashville*  Louisville - 7174-LOU * Closed* On Alert* Inclement Weather closing*
Dallas*  Ft. Worth/ Arlington - 7112-FWA * Closed* On Alert* Inclement Weather closing*
Nashville*  Memphis - 7218-MEM * Closed* On Alert* Inclement Weather Closing*
Phoenix*  Oklahoma City - 7248-OKC * Closed* On Alert* Inclement Weather Closing*
Nashville*  Cincinnati - 7175-CIN * Closed* On Alert* Inclement Weather Closing*
Phoenix*  Tulsa - 7191-TUL * Closed* On Alert* Inclement Weather Closing*
```

and I want to pull out the XXXX-XXX part along with a word.. such as Weather or Power as long as Closed is between them.. So this is what I've got.. and it works.. just seems too generic maybe..and I'm not sure I'm getting the best regex out of it.

So what I want to return is basically 
7109-GAR Weather
7207-PLA Power
etc...

```
(\d{4}-.{3}|\bCAF\b|\bHome Office\b)(?:.+)(?=\bClosed\b)(?:.+)(\bWeather\b|\bPower\b)
```

So lets add this works on Regex101.com but not in my string search in powershell.

Comment: What's wrong with your regex ? It's working.

Comment: It wasn't a question about working/not working.  I was asking for input into better way to do the same thing.  If in fact there aren't any then so be it.. and as I said.. it works on regex101.. but not in powershell.. the ignore capture groups ?: still show up in the return value...so I was kinda hoping I was missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for a shorter and simpler regular expression, and this is what I came up with.

`/(?P<code>\d{4}-[A-Z]{3}).+?Closed.+?(?P<word>Weather|Power)/ig`

Comment: That doesn't include the stipulation that Closed has to be in between code and word as you have it named.  that's where I have the most issue with regex is saying give me this.. but NOT that.. only IF that.. the NOT part is the hardest issue for me it seems

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood your question. I will work on improving my answer. -- I have now corrected my answer.

Comment: Thanks for trying, While the only real change I see is removing the (?:) from the space groups around close, this doesn't really improve the original code and further adds too( adding the naming groups - this wasn't needed ) the original.  I will suppose that what I've got for code is generally the best way to do this.  Thanks